# String indexes must be integers?

Tags: python, json

Hey I am having problems accessing some lists.

I can access `Items` using this code:

```
    data = session.get(BASE_URL + 'tori_market.php',params={'format': 'json'}).json()
except ValueError:
    for item in data['items']:
        print(item['price'])
```

But I can not access `User` using the same code:

```
data = session.get(BASE_URL + 'tori_market.php',params={'format': 'json'}).json()
except ValueError:
    for users in data['user']:
        print(user['max'])
```

Edit: I've posted the wrong code,here is the one i'm using.

```
data = session.get(BASE_URL + 'tori_market.php',params={'format': 'json'}).json()
except ValueError:
    for users in data['user']:
        print(users['balance'])
```

What is wrong with it? 
You can check how the API directory are build in this [link](http://forum.toribash.com/tori_market.php?format=json&explain).

The full traceback is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cristi/Desktop/RealBot/prova.py", line 34, in <module>
    data = session.get(BASE_URL + 'tori_market.php',params={'format': 'json'}).json()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 799, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cristi/Desktop/RealBot/prova.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(users['balance'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

As soon as it's a passworded page i can give you a screenshot,[here](http://grabilla.com/0510d-fecf1f3c-291a-4f92-9be8-78a2839b48cf.html).

Comment: What is the **full** traceback for the error do you get then? Did you verify that `data` has such a key? The documentation link you gave us is password protected, we cannot see anything there without an account.

Comment: And from mu's answer you can see why we need to have the full error message; it'd have given us a clue that it was the `print(user['max'])` line that throws the exception. Do you have a `user` defined *elsewhere* in that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited answer***

the user in above is a key in json data, so when you do

```
for users in data["user"]
```

you are already iterating over its keys.

Instead, for sake of brevity, do,

```
for key in data["user"]:
    print key, data["user"][key]
```

This will print all the data within the user dict for you. So now `key` can take the values of `"balance"` etc.

---

***Original answer***

This is a typo between `users` and `user`, you use:

```
for users in data['user']:
```

but access it as:

```
print(user['max'])
```

Instead access it as:

```
print(users['max'])
```

Comment: Ah, and presumably `user` was defined before and is a string.

Comment: Okey i've modified the first post,added a screen!

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that new query in order to work properly? I'll try it in a few minuts,at the moment i hace some stuff to do and can't access the computer.

Comment: @Cristian Sorry, please ignore that comment, I hadn't seen the image you had attached then. Check edits.. If that helps, don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: And if i want the balance now i can just go like: balan = key['balance'] ?

Comment: if you want `balance` only, then don't use the `for` loop and simply do `data["user"]["balance"]`. When you use the for loop as written in my code, you are iterating over all the keys, so in one iteration, the value for key is string "balance", in another iteration, the value for key is string "max" and so on.